# How do I access Admin page for my OG site and post to feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, admin, facebook-opengraph

Thank you in advance for any help. I have a website which has OpenGraph embedded code, which validates without error in the linter. I have the Javascript SDK called and the XFBML Like button, plus Comments and Recent Activity plugins. They all seem to be working quite nicely. Next to my Like button is the "Admin Page" link, as expected.

The problem is that **clicking the Admin Page link just opens a new window with my website in it.**

I thought it would pull up some kind of page where I could publish stream updates, as described on this reference page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#publishing
But this doesn't happen. May I have some help on why this is happening and how to fix?

Details that may help:

1. When I go to the Pages I Admin area on Facebook (http://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/pages) the page is in fact listed.
2. I have linked the page to my Insights and am receiving data there.
3. The Admin Page link does appear next to my Like button.
4. The URL if you need to see the components working in place: http://mansbestfriendcommercial.com/

The code on my page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MY TITLE"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MY SITE NAME"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="MY DESCRIPTION"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="MY URL"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="MY IMAGE URL"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="MY FACEBOOK USERNAME"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY APP ID"/>
```

And the Javascript SDK call:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MYAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Upvoted,  excellent question and well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was **definitely a bug** rather than a programming or setup issue. The bug has been marked fixed by Facebook as of 1/18/2012 and everything now works as it is supposed to! Bug report:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/308356579205492?browse=search_4f0f1475c470b2076799347

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue and didn't find any solution so far about it :(
Until recently i was able to use the facebook admin page of mu liked pages on my site but don't know what happened i have the same problem like you, i can access the insights but when i visit the admin page link it open a new windows with the same website in it here is a link if someone could check it out: http://www.lajkuvaj.com/44964